# C# only show one specific line from CMD

Tags: c#, arrays, cmd, process, line

I want if the cmd finished only the 10th line shows in the label, but I don't know is it possible or no if yes how?Maybe with array?This program should get when the user password expire.

```
private void AccountBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Process pw = new Process();
        pw.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pw.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pw.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        pw.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net user " + System.Environment.UserName + " /domain";
        pw.Start();
        label1.Text = pw.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pw.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var counter = 0;
while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    counter++;

    if (counter == 10)
    {
            label1.Text = line;
            break;
    }
}
```

Or you could also do (not really worth it):

```
label1.Text = p.StandardOutput
               .ReadToEnd()
               .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                      StringSplitOptions.None)
               .Skip(9);
```

Comment: I tried the first one, but nothing happend.Here is how it look like now:
`pw.Start();
            pw.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var counter = 0;
            while (!pw.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = pw.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                counter++;

                if (counter == 10)
                {
                    label1.Text = line;
                    break;
                }
            }
            pw.WaitForExit();
        }`

Comment: @Tamás When you call `ReadToEnd`, the process maybe hasn't even started to write to the output stream. You probably want to call `ReadToEnd` once the process has finished or is Idle.